# Automatically convert text to number in an updating spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that is being populated, by a separate application, with strings that are numbers (e.g., "654", "0.005"). Excel can't do computations on strings. Since my spreadsheet is updated (rows are appended) every few minutes, I'd like to write script that automatically converts cells in a range to numbers.

Here's my solution, where convertRange is a range that contains strings to be converted to numbers:

```
method OnChangeInSpreadsheet():
if changedCell is NOT in convertRange
   currentHeight = convertRange.height
   expand convertRange to include new rows
   convert the new rows' strings
```

The reason it gets complicated is because a string-to-number conversion would trigger the OnChangeInSpreadsheet function, so I have to be careful that new rows are appended outside of the convertRange. Can anyone think of another solution?

Thank you!

Comment: When using an event handler to make changes to the sheet, you would typically use `Application.EnableEvents=False` before making any changes, so as not to re-trigger the event. Set back to `True` when done!

Comment: That changes everything, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [ASAP Utilities function](http://www.asap-utilities.com/asap-utilities-excel-tools-tip.php?tip=70&utilities=67&lang=en_us), "Change not recognized numbers (text?) to numbers". I decided I do not actually need to convert text to number on every update, so I run the function inside the OnWorkbookOpen method.

It would be easy to run the ASAP Utilities function on just the cells that have been changed. Just turn off Application.EnableEvents before, and turn it on after, as someone so helpfully suggested in the above comments.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried multiplying the string values by 1 so as to be converted to numbers?  I had an issue some days ago with numbers being perceived as strings and not behaving properly.  The solution was to just multiply them by 1.

Let me explain: I coded a module in `VBA` to do some calculations between numbers taken from an `excel` worksheet. The results of the calculations were put in an array and later "printed"(as in assigned) as part of a modified excel formula on another worksheet.  The problem I had was that decimals (e.g. 0.1234) did not show their "0" in front of the "." in the cells.  The issue was that excel perceived them as *strings* and not as *numbers*.  Even when I changed their format through the excel GUI to numbers the problem persisted.

*Note: many times in programming you turn an integer to a double/float by multiplying it by a double/float*.

Having that in mind I *printed* the results in the cells multiplied by 1 `(as in "=function(...) * 1")`, which worked.

Comment: This is more like a comment. You could rather elaborate your answer with the problem you faced, which not only the person here but also anyone searching for a similar problem

Comment: Freakyuser I hope the explanation makes sense. If not please let me know. When it comes to math, my English vocabulary is very limited.

Comment: You will have to wait till the questioner accepts the answer if he finds it useful. I just reviewed and formatted your answer. Thank you for updating though.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple methode to auto-convert strings in whatever needed:

```
Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arrStrData))
```